# Efficient way to add CSV file as records to sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

ASP.Net Core app - which reads a CSV file, and loops through each record to add it to the database.

```
        using (var reader = new StringReader(publicScheduleData))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csvReader.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
            csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
            csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;

            var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Qualys>();

            foreach (var item in records)
            {
                _context.Qualys.Add(item);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

        }
```

I know you can import directly in SSMS, but this has to be an end user function, to update the sql data from a web form.

The above method seems very slow - writing a few records per second. My CSV file has 90,000+ rows, and 26 columns.

Is there a quicker method to add those records to the database?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: The faster way is to use sqmcmd.exe (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).  You can run from Process class and create the parameters list in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert your csv into a datatable and then insert it into the database you should get much faster insert times as you are not doing a single insert at a time. This [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F) may get you on your way. If the approach in the article doesn't work for you, I would still suggest inserting the csv data into a datatable and then using a user defined table to insert the data as a parameter to a stored procedure and then you can do and insert with a select from the user defined table.

Answer (score 1):

The newer version of .NET Core supports [SQLBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.7.2) library. This library will let you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from another source.

Here is example to follow https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/bulk-upload-in-net-core/

```
    using (var sqlCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connString))  
        {  
          sqlCopy.DestinationTableName = "[Products]";  
          sqlCopy.BatchSize = 500;  
          using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(prodlist, copyParameters)) 

           {  
                        sqlCopy.WriteToServer(reader);  
           }  
       }
```

Comment: Is SqlBulkCopy transactional? will it ensure that all the lines in the CSV are added or non at all??